# What is the word or mental state to describe someone that takes any disagreement with them as negative and unacceptable?

Tags: meaning, phrases, tenses

What is the word or mental state to describe someone that takes any disagreement with them as negative and unacceptable?

Is there a word or mental condition to describe someone that takes *any and all* disagreement to them as negativity and being mean?  Can be something as simple as, "I don't think so..." And then respond by getting angry and say that person refuting them is negative?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [person who's too eager to ascribe malicious intent](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172607/person-whos-too-eager-to-ascribe-malicious-intent) (paranoia; cynicism ...) Or [a less harsh substitute for crusty/cranky](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266090/whats-a-less-harsh-substitute-for-crusty-cranky) (crabby, crotchety, grouchy, irascible, peevish, perverse, pettish, petulant, prickly, quick-tempered, raspy, ratty, snappy, snarky, testy, ...)?

Comment: Answers to the alleged duplicate do not cover all aspects of this question. Leave open.

Comment: Also [What's the word for someone who always takes things -personally?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340391/whats-the-word-for-someone-who-always-take-things-personally/340400#340400) (defensive / hypersensitive). And [single word to describe someone who is overly sensitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/single-word-to-describe-someone-who-is-overly-sensitive/63867#63867) (persecution complex).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that they are [defensive](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/defensive):

> 4. *Psychology* Constantly protecting oneself from criticism, exposure of one's shortcomings, or other real or perceived threats to the ego.

Example of how to use it in a sentence:

> When someone feels insecure about something, any disagreement can feel like harsh criticism and cause them to become angry and **defensive**.

Answer (score 0):

This is shaky ground for anyone who is not a professional psychologist (I am not) but common perceptions are that in some cases such a person may be suffering from *paranoia*, *personality disorder* or *persecution complex*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paranoia)
>
> paranoia:
> an extreme and unreasonable feeling that other people do not like you or are going to harm or criticize you

> [Mind: Effects of Paranoia](https://www.mind.org.uk/information-support/types-of-mental-health-problems/paranoia/effects-of-paranoia/#SafetyBehaviours)
>
> If you think someone is threatening you or wants to harm you in some way, you may behave suspiciously or aggressively towards them. You might push them away or decide that you are better off without them.

or you might find that they have a *persecution complex*:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/persecution%20complex)
>
> persecution complex:
> the feeling of being persecuted especially without basis in reality

Both these conditions may result in over-sensitivity to criticism of even the mildest or most reasoned sort, and result in anger against and rejection of the critic.

And lastly, PPD is *Paranoid Personality Disorder*:

> [Helpguide](https://www.helpguide.org/articles/mental-disorders/paranoid-personality-disorder.htm)
>
> A person with PPD may feel deeply wary of others, always on guard for signs that someone is trying to threaten, mistreat, or deceive them. No matter how unfounded their beliefs, they may repeatedly question the faithfulness, honesty, or trustworthiness of others. When they perceive they’re being persecuted, rejected, or slighted, they’re likely to respond with angry outbursts, controlling behavior, or by deflecting the blame onto others.

Answer (score 0):

> A person who takes any disagreement with them as negative and
> unacceptable is **oversensitive / hypersensitive.**

Oversensitivity can contribute to various **anxiety disorders** including **obsessive-compulsive disorder.**

**oversensitive** (adj.)

> Too easily bothered, upset, offended, etc.
>
> *an oversensitive person*
> *oversensitive about his looks*
> *She's oversensitive to criticism.*
> *It is not enough to say "I was only joking", and you ought not to suggest that the recipient is being oversensitive or thin-skinned.*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oversensitive)

> Excessively or unduly sensitive [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/oversensitive)

**hypersensitive** (adj.)

> If you say that someone is hypersensitive, you mean that they get
> annoyed or offended very easily.
>
> *Student teachers were hypersensitive to any criticism of their performance.*  [Collins](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypersensitive)

> Sensitive to an abnormal or excessive degree; over-sensitive. (OED)

---

> Being particularly **hypersensitive** means being somewhat paranoid,
> and that means that *when people challenge me in any way, I think that
> they are in fact insulting me*. [Martin Kantor; ***Obsessive-Compulsive
> Personality Disorder***](https://www.google.com/search?q=disagree%20hypersensitive%20to%20criticism&biw=1017&bih=489&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBuzvM2Ds7pJo1QXJSZT-0ujjEbk7A%3A1644502245990&ei=5RwFYsnMO-_CkPIPv7Gj0As&ved=0ahUKEwiJ09ChqPX1AhVvIUQIHb_YCLoQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=disagree%20hypersensitive%20to%20criticism&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwJQiwZYvRtgjR5oAHAAeACAAY8BiAH1CpIBAzkuNZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (2016)

> What appears to be inherited is a general emotional
> **oversensitivity** which can predispose one to the development of some form of **anxiety disorder.**  [P. De Silva and S. Rachman;
> ***Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Obsessive_compulsive_Disorder/u7ypeq04cggC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=obsessive-compulsive%20disorder%20oversensitive&pg=PA61&printsec=frontcover) (2004)